# Do neurons have any cognition-related continuous-domain effects on other cells?

Tags: neurophysiology, signal-processing

While the inputs and operation of neurons appears to be a rather continuous and complicated process, the output of a neuron is typically thought of as a "spike."  This is a highly discrete kind of output.  At any moment there is a spike, or there is no spike, and there is little ambiguity (to my knowledge).

Are there any outputs of neurons which are more continuous in nature?  I'm looking for signals that act outside of the cell, shaping the behavior of other cells, which flow smoothly and are not encoded using such electrical spikes.

I'm looking at this from a modeling perspective.  Neuron spiking is complicated enough, but I'd hate to miss an entire channel of communication by focusing too hard on the communication built on spiking.